# Flutter build_runner throws InvalidType is not a class element

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation

After updating Flutter to v3.13.0 & Dart v3.1.0 (stable channel as of 23 Aug 2023)

My code generation has broken.

It was working perfectly fine for versions v3.10.6 & Dart v3.0.7.

Here is my `flutter doctor` output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on macOS 13.4.1 22F82 darwin-arm64, locale en-ES)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

I'm using Injectable to generate my factory registration.

But I'm getting `InvalidType is not a class element` error

It seems this is thrown when trying to register the External Module AppRouter from the `auto_route` package.

Here is the code for the External module. Fairly straightforward

```
@module
abstract class AppRouterModule {
  @singleton
  AppRouter get appRouter => AppRouter();
}
```

I've tried switching between different `build_runner` versions but nothing has worked

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Downgrading back to flutter v3.10.6 fixes the issue. But this shouldn't be the case.

Comment: try latest version of the auto_route it shows updated recently

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue, but with drift_dev generated database tables and classes

Answer (score 0):

May be unrelated, but I was having a similar issue, and one of the references to my classes was in the incorrect case, i.e

```
import 'package:my_app/domain/models/responses/Region_response.dart';
```

instead of

```
import 'package:my_app/domain/models/responses/region_response.dart';
```

Once I corrected the case of the reference, my code generation was fine and it didn't generate any Invalid type generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Flutter 3.19.3.
Fixed by updating pods:

- freezed 2.3.2 -> 2.4.7
- build_runner 2.4.5 -> 2.4.8
- json_serializable 6.7.0 -> 6.7.1
- built_value_generator 8.6.1 -> 8.9.1